# Is the Bible literally the word of God?

Tags: bible, inerrancy, inspiration

As someone from a Muslim background, I have noted a major distinction between the Quran and the Bible; The Quran is seen by its adherents as the ipsissima verba of God, while (I've heard) the Bible isn't.

So my question is quite simple, but I haven't been able to google it: Are there any parts in the Bible which are seen literally, unequivocally as the words of a Christian God? I'd imagine there have to be, but on the other hand if it isn't the literal word of God you could say the Bible might have gotten so altered by people over the time that there exists a possibility that no part of the Bible is actually God's word.

Comment: Different Christian groups have different perspectives on the extent to which the authors of the Biblical text were inspired by God. One popular contemporary perspective is described in [The Chicago Statement on Biblical Inerrancy](http://www.bible-researcher.com/chicago1.html), which was signed in 1978 by nearly 300 noted scholars of Christianity.

Comment: It is the word of god, but of course only of the christian god. Since there are more translations, there is one God per bible, for example the King George God, the Luther God and so on. If you want to be absolutely sure, you have to write a bible yourself.

Comment: Could you explain: Do you mean which words in the Christian bibles did God speak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bible affirms that its words are "breathed out by God Himself", and, indeed, God is the author--not men.

> **All Scripture is breathed out by God** and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, and for training in righteousness  2 Timothy 3:16 ESV

In fact, the Scriptures are often referred to as "the word of God".

> For **the word of God** is living and active, sharper than any two-edged sword, piercing to the division of soul and of spirit, of joints and of marrow, and discerning the thoughts and intentions of the heart.  Hebrews 4:12 ESV (many other references as well)

The men who actually physically recorded the words were, in a sense, secretaries.  The message was from God, but they were the ones who wrote them down.  Peter affirms this high view of Scripture, that God's Spirit actively influenced, or "carried them along" in their writing.

> For no prophecy was ever produced by the will of man, but **men spoke from God as they were carried along by the Holy Spirit**.  2 Peter 1:21 ESV

Paul also affirmed that the message he gave to people came from God.

> And we also thank God constantly for this, that when you received the word of God, which you heard from us, **you accepted it not as the word of men but as what it really is, the word of God,** which is at work in you believers.

Furthermore, the Word of God (Bible) itself is not a stale message, but as already noted, is alive and active (Hebrews 4:12).  Jesus Himself also affirmed that His words were spiritual in nature.  This indicates that the Bible specifically communicates with our own spirits in a supernatural manner.

> It is the Spirit who gives life; the flesh is no help at all. The words that I have spoken to you are spirit and life.  John 6:63 ESV

So, in conclusion, the Bible presents itself not as the work of men, but the work of God and, in fact, a spiritual, living, and active communication from God directly to us today.

Comment: This represents one perspective. Certainly not the predominating or pan-Christian answer though ... Might be worth noting that! (At least insofar as it seems to answer *yes, it's God's literal wording*)

Answer (score 4):

**Which came first, Qur'an or Bible?** Bible

**Did the Qur'an fall from the sky?** NO

**Did the Bible fall from the sky?** NO

**Did God(Allah) write the Qur'an with His finger?** NO

**Did God(Jehovah) write the Bible with His finger?** The Ten Commandment was, at least.

**Who wrote Qur'an and Bible?**
Qur'an and Bible were written by men and both claimed to be from God.

**How many authors Qur'an has?** One. Muhammad alone. No one was there to support the ideas of Muhammad. He alone handled the whole situation.

**How many authors Bible has?** Approximately 40 men. All from different times and places with different languages but were writing in harmony to each other.

**How many years Qur'an took to complete?** Approximately 23 years. 100 years later it was put into written form.

**How many years Bible took to complete?** Approximately 1500 years. This has a good historical evidence to prove its authenticity and timelessness.

**Method of communication from God in Islam:** Muhammad was the only person responsible for the origin of Qur'an. He claimed to receive the *last and final* message from God through angel Gabriel. The communication usually took place in the [Cave of Hira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hira). Muhammad was always alone in that cave. Who knows what he was doing! Probably thinking about what will be the contents for the next chapter for his composed book and revising the words that he has to say to his 50-60 companions.

**Method of communication from God in Bible:** There are many countless ways on how God communicated with the authors of the Bible. Some saw a vision. Moses was speaking with God like a friend. Paul saw a great light and met with Jesus. There are many examples.

**Originality of stories from Qur'an:** Most of the stories from Qur'an are borrowed from the Bible with incomplete accounts and many times twisted. Years are not mentioned. There is no sequence. Names are also confusing. Example, Qur'an has no mention of the names of Cain and Abel and also who was the elder or who was the evil one.

> *Surah 5:27*
>   And recite to them the story of Adam's two sons, in truth, when they
>   both offered a sacrifice [to Allah ], and it was accepted from one of
>   them but was not accepted from the other. Said [the latter], "I will
>   surely kill you." Said [the former], "Indeed, Allah only accepts from
>   the righteous [who fear Him].

**Originality of stories from Bible:** The Bible itself is it's own source for it's stories without borrowing it from elsewhere. In fact, it's a historical record of Israel and Christianity.

Comment: One good point from this. Scores of godly man claimed that they heard and received revelations from God and was recorded in the Bible. These revelations of 1500 years corroborated with each other. Muhammad purportedly claimed that he received revelations from God (initially though, he was not sure from where he was getting these revelations, till his wife makes this guess). With little knowledge that he had of Christian teachings, he too tries to corroborate whatever he was hearing in the cave, with the events in Bible. In the end, it was found to be contradicting with 1500 years of record.

Comment: @Seekforgiveness there's a flaw in that argument that I'll like to point out: the fact that 1,500 years of work by different people corroborate each other is less than remarkable when you consider that later writers were well aware of what their predecessors wrote. And also, books that didn't fit the narrative we left out of the canon.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and scripture tells us why people can read the Bible and perceive no life, have no growth.

"Having not the Spirit of God."